# Android: Time calculations, how to add a specified amount of minutes

Tags: android, time

I'd like to add 15 minutes to Time Object, so that 09:46 would become 10:01.

```
 Time time = new Time();
 time.hours = 9;
 time.minutes = 46;
 time.minute += 15;
```

This doesn't work... :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In what way does it not work?

If the problem is you're ending up with 61 minutes, you should call `Time.normalize(boolean ignoreDst)` to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Current library time libraries in Java are troublesome. As mentioned, you better use Joda Time, especially if you are making time computation. Here is your code using Joda.

```
DateTime fromEpoch = new DateTime(0)
      .plusHours(9)
      .plusMinutes(46)
      .plusMinutes(15);

DateTime fromNow = DateTime.now()
      .plusHours(9)
      .plusMinutes(46)
      .plusMinutes(15);
```

More details on DateTime here:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime()

In the upcoming Java 8 a new Joda like time library will be introduced to fill the need:

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html