# Is there a function for adding time in android?

Tags: android

I have 09:30 as a time retrieved from a database, I need to add 15 minutes to get it as 09:45.
Is there a function for adding time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Time calculations, how to add a specified amount of minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985532/android-time-calculations-how-to-add-a-specified-amount-of-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String RevisedTime=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("RevisedEstimatedDeliveryTime"));     

            // get hour and minute from time string
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(RevisedTime, ":");
            int j = 0;
            int[] val = new int[st1.countTokens()];
            // iterate through tokens
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                val[j] = Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
                j++;
            }`enter code here`

            // call time add method with current hour, minute and minutesToAdd,
            // return added time as a string
            String dateRevisedEstimatedDeliveryTime = addTime(val[0], val[1], 15);




public String addTime(int hour, int minute, int minutesToAdd) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToAdd);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html has what you need, using its `add()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    final Calendar cld = Calendar.getInstance();
    cld.setTimeInMillis(time);
   cld.add(Calendar.MINUTE,15)
```

Comment: he need to add minutes,not set them

Comment: I wrote cld.set() instead of cld.add() by mistake.sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

use `Calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE,15)` to get that